# Open React.js project in another project

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a project in react which is almost completed but I have to include my 2yo. react project which is still working if I open it separately.
I tried to add that whole project to my src folder and run it from there but that project is using it’s own redux, router and a lot of other stuff which will take me a years to transfer it.
Do you have any advice?

The project should work like this:
In project 1, you click for example on a button which should open a component from the project 2 and display it on the page..

Comment: You mean, inside one `/src` folder but running seperately, right?

Comment: Then, for now, the question could be "Sharing node_modules folder with multiple projects", right?

Comment: I don't think so but I explained it wrong, check this post again to know how it should work.

Comment: Your quest lacks detail so won't get an answer. How are we supposed to know the differences in compilaton requirements between the two (e.g. webpack/babel config), or what tech/version difference there are (e.g. react router v3 vs v4), or how you want to host it (e.g. different url prefix to each e.g. /legacy/.. and /new/.. or all merged together etc etc :/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can include your project as compiled javascript file in any project.

I have done this but you need to specify a function or class from where you can access your all components.

Create a production build and simply include it into your other project. it will exactly work as you want it to.

Here is how you can import your build

```
<head>
  <script type="" src="./path/to/js/build.js"></script>
</head>
```

Comment: Great! just tell me one thing that how to generate build.js file?

Comment: @MubeenKhan by default when you run

`npm run build` which is react's default behaviour it creates a compiled file for your react app which is build.js in production `ENV` but you can change its name by updating your web pack settings to whatever you like.

Answer (score 0):

I've been in exactly the same situation. I include the old project as any other JS library at the end of the body tag in the same HTML. Root divs have to of course be different for both apps, which you have to configure in the apps code.

It works like a charm, more or less.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

  <title>Two react apps together</title>

</head>

<body>
  <div id="oldRoot"></div>
  <div id="newRoot"></div>
  <script src="./static/js/old.js"></script>
  <script src="./static/js/new.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```